# Не работает add_post_meta, при создании поста, из плагина

Tags: wordpress

Пишу по новой, рассказываю всё. Я в php  не понимаю, только jquery. Перекладываю из jquery на php, пишу функцию для плагина.

function zh_feeds() {

```
$channels = explode('^!^', get_option('zh_channels'));
$channels = explode(',', $channels[1])[0];
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=' . $channels;
$url = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = @simplexml_load_string($url);

$yt_group = $feed->entry[0]->children( 'yt', true );
$cannelID = $yt_group->videoId;

$media_group = $feed->entry[0]->children( 'media', true );
$cannelID = $yt_group->videoId;
$thumbnail = $media_group->group->thumbnail->attributes()->url;
$title = $media_group->group->title;
$video = $media_group->group->content->attributes()->url;
$description = $media_group->group->description;
$viddis = '[arve url="' . $video . '" /] <br><span style="color:#000" class="zh_description">' . $description . '</span><br><p id="zh_comment">КОММЕНТАРИИ</p><br><br>';

//echo $title;

$post_data = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    //'post_excerpt'  => $_POST['post_excerpt'],
    'post_content'  => $viddis,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array(1),
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( wp_slash($post_data) );
var_dump($thumbnail);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'thumbnail-external', $thumbnail );
```

}

Функция парсит YouTube xml ленту, последних публикаций. Всё парсится нормально, ошибок нет. Не могу сохранить миниатюру изображения, миниатюра - это ссылка, т.е., сохранять нужно https:\...
После add/update_post_meta куда то улетает, будь то ни чего не было.
Мне, вообще, не нравится, что приходится из за одной ссылки, сохранять в мета. может можно как поджать местные поля в посту?
Короче, все тексты/ссылки после парсинга чистые. Пробовал через wp_slash() - нет разницы.
Когда вывожу все переменные через echo на страницу, всё нормально, без ошибок, где бы не выводил. Через ajax - выдаёт переменную и следом критическую ошибку.

А var_dump($thumbnail); выдала такое:

object(SimpleXMLElement)#9263 (1) {  [0]=>  string(49) "https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/-sRCnDmr0Qw/hqdefault.jpg"}

На сайте возникла критическая ошибка.

[Узнайте больше про решение проблем с WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/)

Comment: 1. Откуда известно, что не работает? Как проверяли? 2. Что возвращает update_post_meta()? 3. Лучше не использовать add - добавляет много метаданных с одним и тем же ключом.

Comment: Откуда известно, что не работает? Как проверяли?

Проверяю в базе, ни что не появляется, только пост, в мета ни чего не создается.Про мета данные я заметил, плагин ставил для внешних фото.

Comment: На второй вопрос ответьте, плиз. И что выдаёт var_dump($thumbnail)?

Comment: Все переменные нормально выдаются, а после add_post_meta не выдаётся ни чего.

Comment: С такими ответами вам никто не поможет.

Comment: var_dump($thumbnail)object(SimpleXMLElement)#9263 (1) {  [0]=>  string(49) "https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/-sRCnDmr0Qw/hqdefault.jpg"}<p>На сайте возникла критическая ошибка.</p><p><a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/">Узнайте больше про решение проблем с WordPress.</a></p>

Answer (score 0):

Всё, заработало!!! Спасибо за помощь. Помогла очистка esc_url($thumbnail).

Comment: Вместо ответа, добавьте этот текст в сам вопрос. Для этого у вас есть кнопка редактирования вопроса.